# chrome.hid.send fails because device was lost?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app, hid

I get failures on both Macs and PCs when using the `chrome.hid API`.  I can also get successes on both Macs and PCs in a version of the device firmware that always responds with full 64B messages.  The only issue is, I can't control the size of the responses.

## Mac

- Transmitting a message that expects a response fails.

In one test, no message got through until about three or so 5s spaced attempts.  It was only the third attempt that actually set `chrome.lastError` however.

- Transmitting a message that expects no response fails.

## PC

- Transmitting a message that expects a response fails.
- Transmitting a message that expects no response fails.

The messages that come back from this device to the notebook are not necessarily 64B long (58B actually) if that helps any.  The messages being sent to the device are exactly the device's `maxOutputReportSize` which is 64.

## Debug log for PC running Windows 7

My chrome debug log shows the following (see [here](http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging) on how to enable logging and where to retrieve the logs):

```
[21648:18680:1208/133736:VERBOSE1:hid_connection_win.cc(86)] HID transfer failed: The device is not connected. (0x48F)
[21648:18240:1208/133740:WARNING:raw_channel_win.cc(471)] WriteFile: The pipe is being closed. (0xE8)
[21648:18240:1208/133740:WARNING:channel.cc(525)] Failed to send message to remove remote message pipe endpoint ack (local ID 1, remote ID 1)
[8068:21088:1208/133805:VERBOSE1:ipc_sync_channel.cc(386)] Canceling pending sends
```

The device is very much connected and there is no way for me to currently every get an `onDisconnect` event to know otherwise.

Comment: It's important to remember that HID does not have a concept of a response. You have input reports, which are sent from the device to the host (only when the host asks but that's an implementation detail). You have output reports, which are sent from the host to the device. You have feature reports, which are stored by the device and can be updated by the host and read back from the device.

It's hard to tell from the above whether this is an issue with Chrome's HID bindings or some unexpected device behavior. The fact that Windows reports the device disconnected makes me suspect the latter.

Comment: This same firmware (a bootloader) works well with a Windows desktop app built with Qt.  I'm just realizing now that this bootloader resets after about 10seconds and the connection I originally depended on is no longer valid at the point that I attempt to send a message.  I'm in desparate need of an `onDisconnect` method...

Comment: An onDisconnect event is being worked on: https://crbug.com/376719

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The device was indeed lost due to an unexpected timeout internal to the device firmware.  Please disregard.